# How to read only few columns from excel using oledbdatareader in any order in C#.net?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

When I try to read records from the excel using `OLEDbDataReader` class, I am not able to read the column data of each row in any order I want. It throws *Index out of range exception*.

The columns I have are FirstName, LastName, Salary.

```
OleDbDataReader oledbReader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader();

// Doesn't display anything and throws "Index out of range exception".
MessageBox.Show(oledbReader["LastName"]);
```

If I try to read in the order of FirstName,LastName and Salary, it works, but I want to read in any order I want. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You must write the select query in that way  : select col1,col2,col3 from table

Not use select * from table this in the particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

I always read from Excel using the integer column index, and have enums that define the indexes for each column.  So for example...

MessageBox.Show(oleDbReader.GetValue(theColumnEnum.LastName))

Answer (score 0):

you can read in any order, try this:

```
using (OleDbDataReader reader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader())
{

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        a = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        b = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
        c = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();

    }

}
```

In this example I use `reader.GetValue(0).ToString();`becouse I don't know the type of value, but if you know the type you can use reader.GetInt32(0) and other.